# Jira Project Synchronization Tool/Plugin

Tags: project-management, information-management, jira

We need a tool that will synchronize our Jira projects with client's Jira projects. We need to get an update of their new tickets/issues immediately, so it must support 1-way syncing. I've checked unito.io, are there any good alternatives?

Thank you!